OpenVpn: push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp" in server.ovpn not working
I am configuring a VPN server with the configuration below and want to route all client network traffic through this VPN. But when the client connects to the server, the client's default gateway remains unchanged according to the server's default gateway.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 185.228.168.168"
push "dhcp-option DNS 185.228.169.168"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

